# Apache Ignite. Initialize Cache with CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, ignite

I create cache with configuration, which has CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT and CacheStore, that overrided

```
org.apache.ignite.cache.store.CacheStoreAdapter#loadCache
```

When I try call loadCache I get an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Load operations are not supported on transactional caches when MVCC is enabled.
```

But I don't understand why, if I can call putAll() on this cache, what is the difference?

As I understand I should placed initialize logic in other place, but it's looks like a crutch. And maybe it's a wrong way, because not a vain ignite block that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadCache` works differently since it will only populate local data (both primary and backup) on all nodes. `putAll` will only send data over the network. `loadCache` is only consistent when operation is complete, which is not how `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT` works.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: don’t use `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT`. If you need transactions, use `TRANSACTIONAL`.

Currently, MVCC is “beta quality.”

Comment: I use TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT because I use JTA transaction's, and I want get transactional selection. Search criterias are not associated with key. ScanQuery is not transactional and so slow.